# Is there a way to get a Facebook page's name with PHP?

Tags: php, facebook

I'm building an iframe app that will have a few mentions of the Facebook Page is lives on. My app will be added to multiple pages with different names. What I need is something like this..

```
$page_name = "Bob's Toys";

Thank you for visiting the <?php echo $page_name; ?> page!
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Are you saying you want the app to know about the containing Facebook page? Your small code example doesn't really explain it. And by "page name" do you mean literally the title?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there is. Decode the **signed_request** sent to the page by Facebook.

```
if (!empty($_REQUEST['signed_request'])) {
  $signedRequest = $_REQUEST['signed_request'];
  list($sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signedRequest, 2);
  $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);
}
```

From that, you can get the page's id.

```
array (size=4)
  'algorithm' => string 'HMAC-SHA256' (length=11)
  'issued_at' => int 1321635439
  'page' => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string '19292868552' (length=15)
      'liked' => boolean false
      'admin' => boolean true
  'user' => 
    array (size=3)
      'country' => string 'gb' (length=2)
      'locale' => string 'en_US' (length=5)
      'age' => 
        array (size=1)
          'min' => int 21
```

Then you can use the Graph API to return the page object that would look like this: https://graph.facebook.com/19292868552

Comment: Thanks Moz. What I need to get though is the page's name, not the id. I can get the id by doing this.. `if (!empty($_REQUEST['signed_request'])) {
  $signedRequest = $_REQUEST['signed_request'];
  list($sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signedRequest, 2);
  $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);
}

echo $signed_request['page']['id'];` 
 
But when I `echo $signed_request['page']['name'];` I get nothing.

Comment: You can then use the id to perform a request to the Graph API to get the page object - see the bit at the end of my answer :)

Comment: I'm sorry... I'm fairly new to all of this. How would I pull the name from the graph? Thanks for all of your help :)

Comment: No worries Dustin. I would recommend using the Facebook JavaScript SDK: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/ and the FB.api method: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/

Answer (score 1):

Just get the page id, query the graph with `name` field only. something like:

```
<?php
$signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];
list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2);
$data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

if (!empty($data["page"])) {
    $page_info = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/{$data['page']['id']}?fields=name"));
    echo $page_info->name;
}
?>
```

Comment: I just tried your code and it didn't return anything :( Is it weird that if I go to https://graph.facebook.com/116338515048403 it just says "false"?

Comment: Make sure that the page is public (not private or "not published" yet)!

Comment: Its not private or set to not published :-/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$page_profile = $facebook->api('/' . $pageid);
echo "<a href='" . $page_profile['link'] . "'>" . $page_profile['link'] . "</a>";
```

Comment: This doesn't achieve what the OP asked.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

$page_profile = $facebook->api('/' . $pageid);

$page_name = $page_profile['name'];

Comment: consider adding an explanation. otherwise it might not be useful to others who read this.